# The Operation of multimeter

Tags: multimeter

1.Does a multimeter operate With AC voltages?
2.What range of frequency does it operate?

Answer (score 2):

1.) Probably, but you need to read the datasheet to be sure.
2.) Read the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the multimeter, you need to read the specifications.

Virtually all multimeters will read both AC an DC voltage and current. What frequencies they cover depends on the design. A few can only handle low frequencies such as those that  are found in mains power, say, up to 500Hz (some aircraft systems use 440Hz). Others can cover the audio spectrum up to, say, 20kHz. Others can go higher.

You need also to look at how the frequency and waveform effect accuracy. You may find the accuracy drops off above a certain frequency.

Some meters assume a sinusoidal waveform and if you try to measure square waves or other shapes they will not give an accurate RMS reading. True RMS meters **should** process the waveform in such a manner that they give an accurate RMS reading. There is an article on it [here](https://www.toolnerds.com/rms-multimeter-accuracy/) and Fluke claim that their true RMS multimeter is one of the few accurate ones [here](https://www.fluke.com/en-gb/learn/blog/electrical/what-is-true-rms)

Comment: @elliot Alderson thank you so much I got it

Answer (score 0):

Just about every multimeter will work with sinusoidal AC. While the range of frequencies varies, they all support 50 Hz and 60 Hz because those are the two common line frequencies worldwide.

To get more specific than that you will have to read the documentation for the meter. In particular, some meters may not give the correct result when the waveform is not sinusoidal. I encourage you to avoid buying meters for which no real documentation is available.