# Can a regular multimeter measure voltages in 400Hz range?

Tags: integrated-circuit, multimeter, voltage-measurement, high-frequency

I’m building a test bench for some aircraft instruments and I was testing a Bendix 1964771-3 inverter (24 VDC) bought from eBay.

The inverter should have outputs of 129VAC at 370Hz and 12VAC/18VAC at 1110 Hz. The inverter was marked as untested but I was told it was removed from a working aircraft.

I powered up the inverter and checked the outputs with a Unit-T UT33C multimeter, but I did not get any output.

I suspect maybe only the expensive like Fluke, Omega, etc. can measure such high frequency voltages. Could this be the case? Just as a precaution I tried using a neon voltage tester and it immediately lit orange light.

Comment: Rectify to DC and measure on DC with your meter as an alternative proof of voltage presence.

Comment: I measured the 3dB bandwidth on a 20 dollar generic DMM and got about 1.5 KHz. Yours could be anything but I doubt the drop off is so sharp that you would measure 0V at 370 Hz.

Comment: You are basically asking us what reads in your multimeter manual what AC frequency range it can measure. Have you read your multimeter manual?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm going to try this now. Thanks  for the suggestion.

Comment: Make sure you add a light load so that maybe a few milliamps are taken but, calculate the resistor load power dissipation with what you might expect to see if the voltage is present.

Comment: @Justme As per the manual it is supposed to measure upto 400Hz. But I'm getting 0V on measuring. But I'm able to get a measurement if I try plugging to my 120V receptacle. So I know my meter works.

Comment: 400 Hz is not outside of the realm of most multimeters, but only testing like @user1850479 did or check the datasheet will tell for sure.

Comment: This is a repeat of a [closed] question I (amongst others) answered back in May this year https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612864/the-operation-of-multimeter/612868#612868

Comment: @ Peter Jennings I'm just trying to get answers and opinions on what could be causing it. Yes, I know from my meter manual it should be able to to, but for some reason it isn't showing any readings at 400Hz, though there is output can easily light up a neon lamp. Given that we have lot of highly knowledgeable & experienced folks here, I'm hoping with some help I can figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Unit-T UT33C](https://www.sigmaelectronica.net/manuals/UT33BCD%2520Eng%2520Manual.pdf) user's manual says it can handle AC up to 400Hz and 500V.

[image]

It can probably manage the 400Hz (if it meets its specifications.)  It will give totally wrong results for the 1110Hz - either nothing or way too low.